# EXCEL-Extracting Certain Text from left and right of repeating character in a cell

Tags: excel

The following is leaving me quite confused: 
I have a cell, `A1`, with the following data for instance:

```
$31.00 Yrs 1-5 $34.00 Yrs 6-10 $37 Yrs 11-LXD.
```

I am trying to build a function that extracts the dollar amount to the left of `"Yrs"` and prints the corresponding years interval next to it with a `/` in between.

So basically, the output I'd like is something like this:

```
$31.00/1-5 $34.00/6-10 $37/11-LXD.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to best approach this. I'm thinking the solution will comprise `IF` statements with `LEFT`, `MID`, and/or `RIGHT` functions utilized within.

Comment: Simply `SUBSTITUTE` " Yrs " with "/"? https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-b9dcfd8a-6bd8-4784-b128-dca79e4d0e02?CorrelationId=57156e0d-9dab-4415-9000-31c34cb01ea8&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," Yrs ","/")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you. That worked into my existing logical IF statements was all I was missing.